# Returning an string to a View Controller using "prepareForSegue"

Tags: ios, segue

My code is :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
 {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
       NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];
       NSLog(@"Description : %@" , string);

        [[segue destinationViewController] " WHAT TO CODE IN HERE ? "];

    } }
```

I need to show the "string" in NSLog in the viewController . 
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a property to the destination view controller to set the desired string. Then you would be able to reference its value from the destination view controller:

```
@interface DestinationViewController
...
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *theString;
@end
```

Now you can call

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setTheString:string];
```

or

```
DestinationControllerType *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
dest.theString = string;
```

and then reference `theString` when the destination view shows up.

Comment: "setTheString" is not working . shows an error stating - not known  instance method

Comment: You need to include the header for the destination view controller in the implementation file in which you define `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: Yea , i did that . can you brief the "setTheString:string" ?

Comment: @SivabalanBalasubramanian `setTheString` should be generated by default when you declare `theString` property `readwrite`. You can try using the dot syntax as well.

Comment: Yea when i changed it to readwrite it is working perfectly . Thanks a lot .